# Get total cart weight from orders in Opencart 2.0.3.1

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

I'm trying to get the total cart weight, including the converted value from weight class table.

By now, my code looks like this:

```
public function getOrderWeight($order_id) {
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT SUM(p.weight * op.quantity) AS weight FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "order_product op LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product p ON op.product_id = p.product_id WHERE op.order_id = '" . (int) $order_id . "'");
    if ($query->row['weight']) {
        $weight = $query->row['weight'];
    } else {
        $weight = 0;
        $weightsuff = "";
    }
    return $weight;
}
```

This way I'm getting only the weight as is in the database. However, I'd like to get the price using the weight conversion from weight class table `oc_weight_class`. But I couldn't achieve that yet.

I'm trying to accomplish, in human speech, is something like this:

```
get product weight from order table * quantity / weight rate value
to get everything in default weight rate (kg).
```